# Sorting function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I would like to use an older python script with `cmp` function, but it doesn't work in Python 3. It raises an error:

```
TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function
```

I know that I should avoid the `cmp` function and use the key function instead, but I don't know how (I don't know Python and I am not a programmer). Could you please help me to change the following part according to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)?

```
ls = list(self.entries)

def func(key1, key2):
    (w1,l1,t1) = res[key1]
    (w2,l2,t2) = res[key2]
    val = cmp((w2,t2), (w1,t1))
    return val
ls.sort(func)
```

Thank you.

Comment: use `ls.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(func))`. [sorted docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) (`list.sort` refers to that) and [functools docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried now, but I received the message: "NameError: name 'functools' is not defined"

Comment: @PaulRooney: that's overkill for this sort.

Comment: true, I wasn't really looking at his code, just looking at how he could use what he had.

Comment: I added the `import functools` line and now I got the `NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined` again. Somehow the conversion doesn't work yet.

Comment: Thank you @Paul. I think, my latest problem was the same as below: [the script](http://eblong.com/zarf/ftp/rpvote.py) called the `func` function later again, and the `cmp` didn't work there.Now, Martijn's suggestion solved this, too. Sorry, that I didn't provide the entire code at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the first and last element of each tuple you are sorting, but reverse the result:

```
ls.sort(key=lambda t: (res[t][0], res[t][2]), reverse=True)
```

That's exactly what the `cmp` version was comparing on, but in reverse, and the `sort()` method will do so too.

Comment: hmm. I received an "IndexError: string index out of range" message for this code...

Comment: @Sam updated, I had missed your code is sorting based on an external mapping `res`.

Comment: Dear @Martijn Pieters : sorry, I didn't realize you edited your answer. Unfortunately, I am at the same point as before: "NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined" points to the line with `val = cmp((w2,t2), (w1,t1))` :(

Comment: @Sam my answer doesn't use `cmp` at all. Remove all of `func`.

Comment: Ah, I see :) The problem is, that the program tries to call the `func` function later, and after I removed, I receive a "NameError: name 'func' is not defined" error message.

Comment: I think it is easier to help me if you know the full code. I tried to use [this code](http://eblong.com/zarf/ftp/rpvote.py) after I converted using the 2to3.py

Comment: @Sam right, the code is merely reusing `func()` later on to test if `lastkey` would sort differently. Use `(res[lastkey][0], res[lastkey][2]) != (res[key][0], res[key][2])` in its place.

Comment: Thank you. This replacement solved my problem. Best,